# How to pass product data from one component to another in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a component with a list of products, when you click on a specific product via , you are redirected to another editing component for this product. How to transfer information about the selected product from one component to another? Thanks

Comment: Actually it depends what is the relationship between your components - is that parent and child or siblings or different route itself ? Based on this relation, It will be easy to give the solution/suggestion.

Comment: This is a different rout itself. I want to go from "goods" page to "edit concrete good"

Comment: Then you can use state-management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't comment due to low repo, I am going to suggest you to use `state`
https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html